# Codeigniter 3 sessions not functioning correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have dug through all the codeigniter session topics, but have not found any solutions.

I have setup a Login Controller for my project that sends the username and password onto my Login Model. This all works fine. Once I pull the information out of the database, I am setting some session information.

Here are some code snippets:
Config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 14400;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/var/www/mysite.com/application/cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database', 'form_validation', 'email');
```

Pulling an idea from the database (works fine):

```
$UserID = $this->LoginModel->login($username, $pass);
```

Setting a session variable:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('Sess_ID', md5($UserID.date('YmdHis')));
```

After the process is complete, the user is sent to the next page. This is where the problems are.  I load a simple check for the session variables and even a var_dump, but every time the session is empty.

```
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        echo var_dump($this->session);
        if ($this->SessionModel->basic() == false) {
            //$this->SessionModel->logout();
            echo 'Session Error';

        }

    }
```

So, the question is, how can I call the session from the next page/controller? I am used to using the session_start(), but that isn't needed in codeigniter.  I have also confirmed that session files can and are being written to the directory.

Input please...

Comment: what is `$this->session->userdata('Sess_ID');` giving??

Comment: It is currently giving a custom session_ID.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` produce?  (BTW, no need to `echo` var_dump)

Comment: I have confirmed that files are showing in the cached folder.

Comment: The code for sending to the next page is a simple: redirect(Select/index);  taking it to my select controller.

Answer (score 0):

to get all session data 
use:

```
 print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

for specific data:

```
  print_r($this->session->userdata('name_of_the_session_variable');
```

in your case:

```
   print_r($this->session->userdata('Sess_ID'));
```

Comment: print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); simply confirms the same thing that echo var_dump($this-session); does.

Comment: you can access that variable in any controller/model/view by above code once the user has logged in.

Comment: Well, that is the problem, I can't. My test is run after they have logged in. I haves used sessions many times in many projects, this is my first time working with CI. I have followed all instructions I have found.

Comment: are you using an encryption key in the config.php? `$config['encryption_key'] = 'yourkey';`

Comment: and make all the config to default and try again @Kaleb

Comment: I have entered a key for encryption, would you recommend taking that away?

Comment: no, encryption key is required for sessions, i want you to remove whatever configs you made(the one you wrote in your question)

Comment: reseting the config did not solve the problem, however, I built a couple pages from scratch and tested a very simple Session and that seems to work. So, I will start over and try to find what caused the issue. Thank you.